# Downloading videos from Youtube doesn't work via `curl`

Tags: windows-8, video, youtube, curl, mp4

I have opened and downloaded via `curl` some `mp4` file from Youtube via `F12` hotkey (i.e. from developer menu) and have saved it into J.mp4
**but** it cannot be replayed. Someone knows Why ?
It writes

> Program Windows Media Player nemůže přehrát soubor. Přehrávač pravděpodobně nepodporuje tento typ souboru nebo nepodporuje kodek, který byl použit ke komprimaci souboru.

**EDIT** In English
Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The player may not support this type of file or may not support the codec that was used to compress the file.

```
 curl "https://r3---sn-2gb7sn7r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1612475884&ei=jBkcYLX4L_Sjx_APzcqi2AE&ip=94.112.85.61&id=o-APjQCxOVd9eizmQjsUJPsKq0x5brYFkTbWOXtUFZzG1G&itag=396&aitags=133"%"2C134"%"2C135"%"2C136"%"2C137"%"2C160"%"2C242"%"2C243"%"2C244"%"2C247"%"2C248"%"2C278"%"2C394"%"2C395"%"2C396"%"2C397"%"2C398&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=ce&mm=31"%"2C26&mn=sn-2gb7sn7r"%"2Csn-4g5e6nsr&ms=au"%"2Conr&mv=m&mvi=3&pl=16&initcwndbps=1658750&vprv=1&mime=video"%"2Fmp4&ns=TVypPdgRR1h3nIAp81UXWTAF&gir=yes&clen=305476742&dur=21854.997&lmt=1584442356635626&mt=1612449199&fvip=3&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&txp=5531432&n=AMTpbbW0IwSivQ&sparams=expire"%"2Cei"%"2Cip"%"2Cid"%"2Caitags"%"2Csource"%"2Crequiressl"%"2Cvprv"%"2Cmime"%"2Cns"%"2Cgir"%"2Cclen"%"2Cdur"%"2Clmt&lsparams=mh"%"2Cmm"%"2Cmn"%"2Cms"%"2Cmv"%"2Cmvi"%"2Cpl"%"2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIhAMjpP3wg4qY5z95gm38b8bg69TDxhV-xcHSqO9_sVu3zAiBH4022rOnDc6VkpOpGhoCH-F4A3tW6gwtOGHlV32Ol7A"%"3D"%"3D&alr=yes&sig=AOq0QJ8wRgIhAJCvYFZshAgJjPRDdAZHAjvD-AY-pQ3GIWxLY1ynlJZzAiEA4zH54IH1kW95u7hmJ4zPsiqdOwAbJ2HLIMuiiXIsk34"%"3D&cpn=Q6yYENvDZpQ-bRl0&cver=2.20210201.07.01&range=0-49859&rn=11&rbuf=0" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Accept-Language: cs,sk;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3" --compressed -H "Origin: https://www.youtube.com" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Referer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shoVsQhou-8" > J.mp4
```

THE FILE SEEMS TO BE BINARY:

[image]

**EDIT** RESULT OF SMPLAYER : edned with error :-(

[image]

Comment: Please translate the error message into English

Comment: Did you bother to look at what was IN the file?  Start with notepad.  Then a hex editor if needed.  It is very possible that you don't have your file at all but a reference to another URL in plain text.  If it isn't full of binary data, then it is not a movie file.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas See my edit. I do not know how to start `hex editor`. However all the file looks alike there are the same symbols at almost all places in it.

Comment: PERFECT!  Your screen shot is fine. :)

Comment: I am guessing that you downloaded this file perfectly.  You simply don't have a decoder to play it.  My suggestion #1 [SMPlayer](https://www.smplayer.info/)  and #2 [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) .. see if those work (I bet they will).  In my opinion, both are far better than windows media player.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas It writes: "Mplayer ended with error. More information in log"! How do I open `log` and why it ended with error ?? I have already VLC but it **still** cannot replay that `mp4` So both of your suggestions have failed (even after and before renaming that `mp4` to `.mpeg`).

Comment: I am not always correct ;)  it looks like your file is not containing everything.  You should look into the answer from @burnt.melon regarding the tool he mentions.  Sorry if I wasted your time.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas You didn't waste my time, I was happy to try everything that might work. The thing is that I need for some hidden reasons understand what's wrong with YouTube and curl. The procedure with extension .acc works fine but not with .mp4 :-(

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas The binary file mentiones `iso` in its body. How could I replay it if it were really `iso` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119379/discussion-between-senor-cmasmas-and-user2925716).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I cannot chat, my account has been suspended. The best thing we can try is that I'll give you a link to the binary file in question and you'll try to run it: [here it is called J.mp4](https://uloz.to/file/oD0ScjcNRTso/j-mp4) Luckily I can write comments!

Comment: This file appears to be a fragmented mp4 stream.  I think the file is broken.  `Playing: D:/Users/duder/Downloads/J.mp4
[ffmpeg/demuxer] mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2: could not find corresponding trex
[ffmpeg/demuxer] mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2: error reading header
[lavf] avformat_open_input() failed
[ffmpeg/demuxer] mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2: could not find corresponding trex
[ffmpeg/demuxer] mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2: error reading header
[lavf] avformat_open_input() failed
Failed to recognize file format.`

Comment: It is possible that you simply do not have the codec to play it but if VLC and SMPlayer will not play it out of the box, then the file is probably broken.\

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Right, try yourself to press `F12` and download with `curl` some of the `mp4` fragments. How do I make them play in SMPlayer ? Do you mean that everything in the developer menu is broken from it's very beginning ?

Comment: Even without curl, I am unable to play the downloaded file.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Do you happen to know **why exactly** and how to fix it ?

Comment: Sorry man.  I do not.  I didn't use CURL and I couldn't open the file either.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Which file you could not open ?

Comment: J.mp4 from the link you provided.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Well, you must click on "Stáhnout pomalu zdarma 0 Kč" on the r.h.s. button. And *not* "Stáhnout rychle za kredit" Is it better now ?

Answer (score 0):

Its probably blocked by YouTube somehow so I dont know how you can get past that but... there is a tool called "youtube-dl" I found which can do the same thing.

Comment: No no :-) I need `curl` and understand **why** it cannot be replayed.

Comment: @user2925716 - Are you sure you're using curl?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, I have installed it and the first word in the cmd widnow is `curl` indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should uninstall your YouTube app and go to Google and search for modern YouTube app since it might be the problem

Comment: I have no Youtube app. I have and need `curl`. What's wrong is the content of the file downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You have downloaded fragment of the dash stream in moov mp4 format. It's need to either merge it with the stream start fragment, or force the browser to switch to playing the webm stream